# Cannot detect vibrate mode while DND on

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am trying to figure out if the user has vibrate mode on. Usually...

```
audioManager.getRingerMode()
```

...returns

> AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.

However when `Do Not Disturb (DND)` is on, `getRingerMode()` returns `RINGER_MODE_SILENT (0)` even if the ringer is set to `RINGER_MODE_NORMAL` or `RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE` by the user.

I also tried:

```
Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.VIBRATE_ON, 0);
```

...but that returns 0 while vibrate mode is on regardless of DND status so it's useless.

This makes it difficult to tell what the ringer is set to when DND is on. You can guess if it's on RINGER_MODE_NORMAL by also checking audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING). However it's impossible to tell whether the mode is RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.

We can set the ringer modes (and see them in the status bar) independently of DND, so why can't we detect the ringer mode when DND is on?

This is on Android Q Beta 6 but I have also confirmed it on Android Pie. Confirmed it's **not** a problem on Android 6.0.1, so not sure when this became an issue, but most likely with Android N when setRingerMode also changed DND.

Logged a bug report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140342727).